# Why is All Pairs Shortest Paths not finding some paths between subnets?

Tags: charts, neo4j, cypher

For example In my case there should be path from sub2 to sub6 and sub2 to sub8, sub2 to tgw2 etc.. But I am not getting any of these paths.

My data:

```
CREATE 
(s1:Subnet{name:"sub1"}),
(s2:Subnet{name:"sub2"}),
(s3:Subnet{name:"sub3"}),
(s4:Subnet{name:"sub4"}),
(n1:Network{name:"net1"}),
(s1)-[:SUB_OF]-> (n1),
(s3)-[:SUB_OF]-> (n1),
(s2)-[:SUB_OF]-> (n1),
(s4)-[:SUB_OF]-> (n1),
(s5:Subnet{name:"sub5"}),
(s6:Subnet{name:"sub6"}),
(s7:Subnet{name:"sub7"}),
(s8:Subnet{name:"sub8"}),
(n2:Network{name:"net2"}),
(t1:TGW{name:"tgw1"}),
(t2:TGW{name:"tgw2"}),
(s5)-[:SUB_OF]-> (n2),
(s6)-[:SUB_OF]-> (n2),
(s7)-[:SUB_OF]-> (n2),
(s8)-[:SUB_OF]-> (n2),
(s5)-[:CONNECT_TO]->(t1),
(s3)-[:CONNECT_TO]->(t1),
(s4)-[:CONNECT_TO]->(t2),
(s8)-[:CONNECT_TO]->(t2);
```

my Projection is:

```
MATCH (src:Subnet)-[r:SUB_OF | CONNECT_TO]->(trg:Network|TGW)
RETURN gds.graph.project(
  'cypherGraph10',
  src,
  trg,
  {relationshipType: type(r)},
  {undirectedRelationshipTypes: [type(r)]
})
```

I am not getting all y\my answers after trying this:

```
CALL gds.allShortestPaths.stream('cypherGraph10') YIELD sourceNodeId, targetNodeId, distance
WHERE gds.util.isFinite(distance) AND sourceNodeId <> targetNodeId
WITH gds.util.asNode(sourceNodeId) AS source, gds.util.asNode(targetNodeId) AS target, distance
WHERE NONE(n IN [source, target] WHERE n:Network|TGW)
RETURN source.name AS source, target.name AS target, distance
ORDER BY distance DESC, source ASC, target ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set the `undirectedRelationshipTypes` incorrectly. Use the following instead:

```
MATCH (src:Subnet)-[r:SUB_OF|CONNECT_TO]->(trg:Network|TGW)
RETURN gds.graph.project(
  'cypherGraph10',
  src,
  trg,
  {relationshipType: type(r)},
  {undirectedRelationshipTypes: ['*']})
```

The problem lay with you setting the `undirectedRelationshipTypes` dynamically. The graph projection will only set to undirected those relationships that have the type to whatever value `type(r)` has for its first invocation i.e. the type of the relationship `r` in whatever happens to be the first record from the `MATCH` clause. For example, if the first record happens to have relationship with type `SUB_OF`, then only those relationships will be undirected in the projection.

The reason this matters is that APSP will only traverse directed relationships following their direction. If you look at your graph, if all the `CONNECT_TO` relationships were directed, then the graph would be partitioned at the green `TGW` nodes:

[image]

And in that case, you will get no paths connecting sub2 to sub6.